# Rewrite Autodiscover to autodiscover with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, autodiscovery

How can I use modrewrite to rewrite the requests made by testconnectivity microsoft com

I want to rewrite

Redirect URL: https://autodiscover myhost com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

to

Redirect URL: https://autodiscover myhost com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

BEFORE it would get proxypassed:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyRequests Off
  SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  #RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteRule   ^/Autodiscover  /autodiscover  [R]   <<< DOESNT WORK


  ProxyPass /autodiscover http://127.0.0.1:5000/autodiscover retry=0
  ProxyPass /ews http://127.0.0.1:5000/ews retry=0
  ProxyPass /_debug http://127.0.0.1:5000/_debug retry=0

  <Proxy http://127.0.0.1:5000>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We don't do your work for you, we're here to help you troubleshoot the work you've done.